# Wordpress app with Cordova

Tags: wordpress, cordova

I have a Wordpress hosted application and I need to create a mobile version of it. As I read in one article, there is a way create a mobile application from hosted web application (not sure if that technique has any particular name). I was able to create the mobile application but I ran into a issue; when I am redirecting to any page, the mobile application is opening the browser to show the page. After some research I found that the solution will be to change all the href to window.open(url, '_system'). Is there any easier way to solve this issue?

The same article shows how to use the Camera plugin with the hosted ASP.Net application. Could anyone suggest an article that shows how to do the same thing but with Wordpress application.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at [WordPress hybrid project](https://github.com/shprink/wordpress-hybrid-client) if you are looking for managed and performance enhanced app.

Otherwise, you can also use inAppBrowser for easy and fast development here is a [Docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/).

Comment: thank you Arpit for your answer, that was hey helpful, I was trying your second solution, to open the hosted application using inAppBrowser. But i encountered a problem: when clicking any link in the hosted application, the application is opening inside the Mobile browser and not staying inside the inAppBrowser. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: yes, there is. Please post other Question for that as it is not part of this Question-Answer. and don't forget to add code in your question so that others can answer it easily.